# Returning incomplete JSON data from controller - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJS and trying to work on a Single Page Cart functionality using AngularJS 1.x. I have a JSON data from where I am showing my product list. The view is below:

[image]

When I am clicking the 'More Info' button it is rediredting to a product details page. While doing so I am encountering an error:

*SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input*

The reason behind it is the JSON data. The JSON data that is retrieved during the call is not a complete one, hence the error. Logged JSON data is below:

**{"p_id":"1","p_name":"cotton tshirt","p_variation":"solid green","p_style":"ms13kt1906","p_selected_color":{"name":"blue","hexcode":"**
Thus I am getting the below view:

[image]

My controller code is:

```
angular.module('myApp.product.controllers', []).
controller('ProductsController',
['$scope', '$log', '$http', '$state',
function ($scope, $log, $http, $state) {

    $log.log('inside product controller');
    $http.get('data/cart.json').
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.products = data.productsInCart;
    }).
    error(function () {
        $log.log('could not find cart.json');
    });    
}]).
controller('ProductDetailsController',
['$scope', '$log', '$stateParams',
function ($scope, $log, $stateParams) {

    $log.log('inside product details controller ' + $stateParams.product);
    $scope.eachData = JSON.parse($stateParams.product);

}]);
```

The 'Partial' code is:

```
<div class="container main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img ng-src="img/{{eachData.p_image}}" class="img-responsive" alt="product image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption-full">
                    <h4 class="pull-right">{{eachData.p_originalprice}}</h4>
                    <h4><a href="#">{{eachData.p_name}}</a></h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
                    <p class="text-right">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My module code is:

```
angular.module('cartApp.product').config([
    '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider',
    function($locationProvider, $stateProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('products', {
            url: '/products',
            controller: 'ProductsController',
            templateUrl: 'module/products/views/products.html'
        });
        $stateProvider.state('productsDetails', {
            url: '/details/:product',
            controller: 'ProductDetailsController',
            templateUrl: 'module/products/views/details.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

In my url I am getting the entire JSON data, but when I am trying to retrieve it and use it for my view page, the JSON data returned is incomplete, hence the error.

Please help me understand the problem why the returned JSON data is incomplete when I am using it in my controller.

Guide me to a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: from where are you getting the json to details page? Can you provide some more code or some jsfiddle simulating this behaviour?

Comment: I have my JSON file in my local directory and I am using `$http.get('data/cart.json').
     success(function (data) {
      $scope.products = data.productsInCart;
     })`
to access the json.
I have edited the controller code above for a better understanding.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the entire JSON string as a URL parameter? That's probably not a good idea.

Comment: $stateParams.product is the product name you clicked. You must find the $stateParams.product key inside the $scope.products and add it to $scope.eachData.

Comment: Can you show the code when you click on the button?

Comment: @BrianGlaz I am not passing the entire JSON data in the url but only a part of it, to get the data for each product. The JSON is something like this, `{  
   "productsInCart":[ {.1.}, {.2.}, {.3.}, {.4.} ] }`. I am passing the entire '1' block in the url and using $stateParams I will be able to access other key/values.

Comment: You would never really want any JSON in your url. Typically your url would be something like `/details/1` where `1` would be the product id. Then in your controller, you would look up the product data given that id.

Comment: @Subhashini I am able to access the JSON and it is coming fine except the fact that it is not logging/returning the complete object (the '1' part from my above comment)

@ValterJunior `<a href="#details/{{product}}" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>` in this {{product}} I am able to pass the entire object block

Comment: @BrianGlaz thank you for the suggestion and will optimize it accordingly but my main concern remains. Incomplete JSON return when i am logging it from my controller

Comment: It also might be cutting off because I'm guessing `hexcode` starts with a `#` sign yes? If that's in the URL it's probably being treated as a URL hash when being parsed through the stateParams.

Comment: @BrianGlaz It doesn't seem that way. My url reads, `localhost/sp-cart/app/#/details/%7B%22p_id%22:%221%2...` i deliberately kept the hash  which is by default an AngularJS thinggy. :)

Comment: but does your JSON file have something like `"hexcode": "#0000FF"`? I have a feeling the '#' might be breaking something because that's exactly where your JSON is getting cut off. Also, there is a max limit to the number of characters allowed in a URL, so I don't know if that might be an issue too.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Yes I have # in my hexcode and that might be a problem as you mentioned but if that is the case what should be the solution.
Max limit to url - In my url all the object key/values are showing without any problem.

Comment: If you can edit your JSON and remove the `#` signs that would be the easiest. You can always add them back in your templates.

Comment: @BrianGlaz , yes was thinking the same. Anyway, thanks for the heads up.  :)

Comment: @BrianGlaz its working fine now. Hexcode # did messed up my mind. Thank you everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BrianGlaz I was able to solve the problem. My JSON had # values for hexcode. That was causing the break. Now its working fine after removing the # from all the hexcode.

Thanks to all for taking time out to read and respond to my query.